# Age & Ability identification

Tags: javascript, html, verification

I was making a poll based on how many developers and nerds/geeks that could program and/or work with electronics were voting for which candidates, and I made this script for verify that they were eligible. However, it doesn't work in the browser and doesn't work on W3's Try It. I've checked that individual sections work in the address bar like

```
javascript:var age = prompt("How old are you?");
```

but when I loaded the page it wouldn't do a thing.

Here is the page, could somebody please help me?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Age Verification</title>
<script>
function verify() {
var age = prompt("How old are you?");
var dev = prompt("Do you develop websites, applications, or work with electronics?");
if (age < 14) alert("You are too young to be using this poll") window.open("www.google.com");
if (dev == "no") alert("You may not vote in this poll, as it was designed for calculating the opinions of these people");
if (dev == "yes" && age >= 14) window.location.href = 'main.php';
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
verify();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have searched and searched for a way, but have not found one.

Comment: `age` is a string. You need `if(parseFloat(age) < 14)` or the weirder but legal `if (+age < 14)`

Comment: @Wainage through type coercion, that part works perfectly fine in JS. But without using curly braces, window.open(google) is not inside any condition, and will therefore always be executed. theasdfguy555, "doesn't work" is a pretty poor description of the problem/error. You want to improve that?

Comment: Thank you both! It finally brings you to main.php if you get everything right.

Answer (score 1):

When I run this page, I get this:

> SyntaxError: missing `;` before statement (8:63)

There I saw this offending line:

```
if (age < 14) alert("You are too young to be using this poll") window.open("www.google.com");
```

And indeed, a `;` was missing after the `alert`, and I inserted it:

```
if (age < 14) alert("You are too young to be using this poll"); window.open("www.google.com");
```

... and it started doing something.

Then I found that a new window is opened even if I enter an age of 14 or more. Ah, there should also be braces around that:

```
if (age < 14) {
    alert("You are too young to be using this poll");
    window.open("www.google.com");
}
```

End of debugging session.

Lessons learned: always check for errors in the console. Note the line, spot the error and fix it.